# .mdf created in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008

my colleague created .mdf and .ldf files from Visual Studio. Now, I'm trying to access the file in SQL Server. There seems to be a problem with this. Can anybody tell me what edition of SQL Server must I have on my Windows Vista 32-bit, so I can access this database. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: What error message do you get when trying to attach the DB?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is tagged [visual-studio-2008]. That version of Visual Studio is bundled with SQL Server 2005 (if you have the proper edition) and the builtin tools uses SQL Server 2005. However, there is nothing in Visual Studio 2008 that prohibits you from using say SQL Server 2008 if you want to. But I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

The MDF and LDF file format is identical between all SQL Server editions that *are at the same build number*. Your friend's Visual Studio by default installs SQL Server Express 2008, and the Express is updated automatically by Microsoft Update and Windows Update to the lates released service pack. Since there is no supported downgrade path for MDF files, your own SQL Server has to match at least the latest Express edition pushed through Windows Update, so you'll most likely need SQL Server 2008 SP1 (build 2007.100.2531.0).

To verify what version of SQL you have and your friend has, follow the steps described in [How to identify your SQL Server version and edition](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/321185)